# Transcode media files from one format to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am working on RoR website and uploading the videos on S3 using paperclip gem and now i want to implement Elastic transcode for videos, but i have know idea how to proceed it.

Please can any one guide me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the developer guide? Seems like it illustrates the entire setup process. Here is a link (warning PDF): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/elastictranscoder-dg.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSYHdt1TJVQ#t=159) on Amazon give all theory you need to understand the process.
Give a try to [Elastic Transcoder gem](https://github.com/ronald05arias/elastic_transcoder). It looks like it has really simple interface.

```
# getting pipeline
pipeline_front = ElasticTranscoder::Pipeline.new
pipeline_front.pipeline "pipeline_id"

# creating a job
jobs_front = ElasticTranscoder::Jobs.new
jobs_front.create_job "input_id", "output_id", "pipeline_id", "preset_id", "thumbnails_pattern"
```